# True or False. Convergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is the statement true or false?

> If $(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence,then $(x_n)$ is bounded.

The statement is False.

However, can someone please show me an example of a sequence with numbers to make it easier to understand. Thank you.

Comment: $1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,7,0,8,0,9,0,10,0,11,0,12,0,\ldots $

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
x_n=\begin{cases}
1,&\quad\text{if $n$ is odd};\\
n,&\quad\text{if $n$ is even}.
\end{cases}
$$